# Writing in a specific format to a txt file in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write `theta` in a specific format to a `.txt` file. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np

theta = np.pi/3

with open('Contact angle.txt', 'w+') as f: 
    f.write(f"theta = {str(theta)}\n")
```

The current output is

```
theta = 1.0471975511965976
```

The expected output is

```
theta = pi/3
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `f.write("theta = pi/3 \n")`

Comment: Yes because I am changing ```theta``` and I want it to write automatically to the txt file in this format.

Comment: What should be the output if the code is changed to `theta = 1.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy doesn't understand symbolic math, so that's not going to work. What you should probably use instead is [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

```
>>> import sympy
>>> theta = sympy.pi / 3
>>> theta
pi/3
```

And if you need to convert it to `float`, you can do that:

```
>>> float(theta)
1.0471975511965979
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not code it like this:

```py
theta = "pi/3"
with open('Contact angle.txt', 'w+') as f: 
    f.write(f"theta = {theta}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write `theta` as a `string` and use the function `eval` to get the value of theta like this:

```
from numpy import pi

theta = "pi/3"

with open('Contact angle.txt', 'w+') as f: 
    f.write(f"theta = {theta}\n")
```

the output of `eval(theta)` will be `1.0471975511965976`

Answer (score 0):

This might be a job that is best suited for [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

If theta will always be `pi/<integer>`, then you could do something like

```
import numpy as np

theta = np.pi/3
divisor = int(np.pi/theta)

with open('Contact angle.txt', 'w+') as f: 
    f.write(f'theta = pi/{divisor}\n")
```

The code will have to get a lot more fancy if theta is always some fraction of pi: `theta = <integer1>pi/<integer2>`

Comment: FYI, I posted [an answer using SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73639313/4518341)